# Hide multiple containers using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, show-hide, jquery-events

I have several dozen objects with an image and a share button on a page at any given time, such as this:

```
<li class="entry" id="sjDDulC8wt"> 
    <img src="sjDDulC8wt.jpg" />
    <div class="entry_actions">
    <ul class="entry_actions">
        <li class='share_it'><a onclick='javascript: showShare("sjDDulC8wt");' 
        onblur='javascript: hideShare("sjDDulC8wt")' target='_self' 
        title='Share It' class='share_it'>o</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="share_options_container"style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="facebook">F</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="twitter">T</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="pinterest">X</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `showShare()` function simply opens the share_options_container div inside that particular element of the page when I click on the anchor tag inside the `entry_actions` ul. When I click off of it, the `hideShare()` function is supposed to hide it.

```
function hideShare(id){
$('#' +id+'.share_options_container').hide();
}
```

When I click on an anchor tag, the corresponding share container div shows up perfectly. When I click off, nothing happens. I've also tried this code, which I found on another similar question:

```
$("body").click(function(){ $(".share_options_container").fadeOut(200); });
```

However, when I click on one of the anchors, this function immediately starts fading it back out, so if I changed the fade to hide then the container wouldn't even pop up at all.

Is there an event I can associate my original `hideShare()` function with such that it will actually trigger when I click off of the anchor tag? If not, can I modify the second function so that it doesn't hide the particular container I'm trying to show as soon as it pops up?

Comment: You should not mix adding handlers like you are. Use jQuery methods to add them all within `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()`. It's possible that's where your problem lies.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I've only been working with JQuery for this week and besides that I have no experience with javascript.

Comment: You're using `onclick=""` and `onblur=""`, which you should refrain from in general, but when using jQuery, they can end up interfering with each. Use one or the other, and use jQuery. Also, why are you using `blur` to close? The user couldn't even use the toggled-to-view elements if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<li class='share_it'><a href="javascript:;" title='Share It' class='share_it'>o</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".share_it a").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".entry").find(".share_options_container").show();                
    })
$(".share_options_container").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();              
    })
```

​
​
**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/JP2Vx/2/

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo for me. The onblur still does nothing though. If I switch the onblur to onmouseout it disappears, but the container is slightly above the anchor so I can't actually get to it before it disappears. Are there any other events I might be able to use?

Comment: Still having the same problem, it pops up fine when I click on it, but doesn't disappear when I click off. I can't find any other events I could associate it with.

Comment: I have dozens of the elements on the page, each with a unique alphanumeric id in the outermost li, where "sjDDulC8wt" is in the example above. How could I pass that into the javascript?

Comment: @jaimerump - You shouldn't need to pass anything to it; `this` is right there. mgraph, you can use `.toggleClass()` and have one handler for the show/hide functionality.

Comment: @mgraph - Are you hardcoding a unique `id` value into the `$.click()` handler?

Comment: @mgraph I had to change the id in `closest()` to "entry", but other than that it works perfectly, thanks! I'm really starting to like JQuery.

Comment: I also have an infinite scroll script on the page, and for some reason this only seems to work on the items that are up when the page first loads. The code for all the elements loaded later is identical, but clicking on them does nothing.

Comment: @jaimerump post this as new question, and provide some script

Answer (score 1):

You should stop the click event from bubbling to the document when you click on the anchors..

so try

```
$(".share_it a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // this line stops the bubbling..
    showShare( $(this).closest(".entry").attr("id") );                
});
$('body').click(function(){
    $(".share_options_container").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so say you have something like this (I've randomly modified each `id`, but you can ignore that anyway, note no inline handlers in the markup like `onclick=""` or `onblur=""`):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="entry" id="sjDDulC8wt">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz" />
        <div class="entry_actions">
            <ul class="entry_actions">
                <li class='share_it'>
                    <a href="#" title='Share It' class='share_it'>Open Options Container</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="share_options_container non-displayed">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="facebook">F</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="twitter">T</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="pinterest">X</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="entry" id="sjDDulC8wtf">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz" />
        <div class="entry_actions">
            <ul class="entry_actions">
                <li class='share_it'>
                    <a href="#" title='Share It' class='share_it'>Open Options Container</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="share_options_container non-displayed">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="facebook">F</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="twitter">T</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="pinterest">X</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    ... More rows ...
</ul>
```

Then you can do this:

**CSS**

```
.non-displayed {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $entries = $('.entry');

    function toggleShare(){
        $(this)
            .parents('.entry')
            .find('.share_options_container')
            .toggleClass('non-displayed');
    }

    $entries.find('a.share_it').bind('click', toggleShare);
    $entries.find('div.share_options_container').bind('mouseleave', toggleShare);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/vg3n5/1

That's why I say you don't the `id` sent in with the handler call or whatnot.

Note, the `mouseleave` idea I stole from mgraph's answer.